# The movie is a sensation that has everyone excited

Tags: grammar

I learned a sentence from language magazine.
The movie is a sensation that has everyone excited. <-- from magazine

The movie is a sensation that everyone has excited.  <-- I think that should like this.

why the verb "has" is not located between everyone and excited.

Answer (score 1):

> The movie is a sensation that has everyone excited.

This is grammatical. *The movie* is the subject, and *the movie* is making everyone excited. "to have X excited" means "to cause X to become excited." The object X (in this case, "everyone") comes between the word "have" and the adjective "excited".

"The movie is a sensation that everyone has excited" does not work, because *everyone* is not the subject - *everyone* is not doing anything. This wording makes it sound like *everyone* is causing the movie to become excited, which makes no sense.

Another wording that does work that has a verb after the word "everyone" is "The movie is a sensation that everyone *is* excited *about*."

Answer (score 1):

Normally, OP would be correct. However, this is a particular construction. I imagine it's similar to *"shot him dead"*; **the movie is causing everyone to become excited.** The people are not exciting the movie; the people are excited by the movie.

**"everyone" is a direct object here; "excited" describes "everyone".**